# What is align_state?

Tags: tex-core, alignment

Here is section 309 of TeX:

> The input routines must also interact with the processing of `\halign` and
> `\valign`, since the appearance of tab marks and `\cr` in certain places is
> supposed to trigger the beginning of special〈vj〉template text in the
> scanner. This magic is accomplished by an `align_state` variable that is
> increased by 1 when a ‘`{`’ is scanned and decreased by 1 when a ‘`}`’ is
> scanned. The `align_state` is nonzero during the〈uj〉template, after which it
> is set to zero; the〈vj〉template begins when a tab mark or `\cr` occurs at a
> time that `align_state` = 0.
>
> 〈Global variables 13〉+≡
> `align_state: integer; {group level with respect to current alignment}`

Indeed, in §342 we see

```
if cur cmd ≤ car ret then
  if cur cmd ≥ tab mark then
    if align state = 0 then 〈Insert the〈vj〉template and goto restart 789〉
```

and in other sections `align_state` gets incremented and decremented as stated.

But some uses of `align_state` are not so clear to me. It is set to 1000000 in
several places (§88, §331, §482, §483, §486, §785, §789, §791). It is set to
−1000000 in §339, §774, and §777. It is set to 0 in §324 and §778. So it seems
as though `align_state` is a little more than than the current group level.

What actually is `align_state`? What is the significance of setting it to
±1000000?

Comment: For instance, in an alignment, `\iftrue{\else}\fi` will increment the group level counter, but not `align_count`. See page 385 of the TeXbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important point is the non-zero part: Whenever TeX encounters a tab-mark or `\cr` and `align_state` is zero, TeX executes the code to insert a vj template.

Of course the maybe more obvious use for this is to ensure that braces are balanced, but in addition to this it is also used to ensure that you are actually in an alignment: Whenever TeX is outside of an alignment, `align_state` is set to 1000000 (plus the brace balance). This ensures that TeX does not try to insert a non-existing vj template if you use `\cr` or a tab-mark outside of an alignment.
Here 1000000 does not have any real meaning except for being big enough be easily reached by a document with lots of unmatched braces in an alignment.

Similarly, `-1000000` (+ the brace balance) is used as a marker that you are reading the alignment preamble (where again, tab-marks and \cr should not insert the vj-template but have a custom meaning).